Device() class of pySMART only recognises one of my two hard drives
Details of my problem:
The Device() class recognises only one of my drives. Only the system drive (a 256GB WD). With the C:\ mountpoint. It is a NVMe SSD btw. It has a PCI-e connector, it is on the motherboard. The other drive, which is my purely-for-data-storage drive (a 2TB Toshiba HDD) it remains unrecognised. It has a 3.5 inch SATA connector. It's not on the list created by pySMART's Device() class.
Note: In the UEFI; The boot order is the following: 1.) Pendrive, 2.) Optical, 3.) WD NVMe SSD
Question: Could the Boot order be responsible for the faulty ways of pySMART's Device() class?
Attempt:
-I tried to print the list.
Expectation:
-I expected to see my other drive on the list.
Result:
-I did not see it.
Attempt:
-I tried to search for possible causes on the internet. I tried to read the doucmentation for example.
Expectation:
-In hope to find a solution.
Result:
-None.
Attempt:
-Asked ChatGPT what is the problem's cause, and how to fix it.
Expectation:
-My hope was, that it can give me an answer, that is sensible, and which I can work with.
Result:
-None. (It told me, that I should use other packages other than pySMART to read SMART data, if pySMART doest't do the trick.) (I only can read values such as vendor, model name, ect. succesfully with pySMART, so others won't do the trick.)
Honestly, all of my attempts were these.
P.S.: Here's the project's GitHub link.
P.S. 2: Code snippet, that contains the pySMART part of the program:
from pySMART import Device
from pySMART import DeviceList
from pySMART import Attribute

try:
    print("="*5, "Háttértár(ak)kal kapcsolatos információk:", "="*5)
    hattertarLista = DeviceList()
    for hattertar in hattertarLista.devices:
        eppenVizsgaltHattertar = hattertar
        print(f"--> Háttértár gyártója: {eppenVizsgaltHattertar.vendor}")
        if str(eppenVizsgaltHattertar.family) == "None":
            print(f"--> Háttértár termékcsaládja: Nem sikerült lekérni.")
        else:
            print(f"--> Háttértár termékcsaládja: {eppenVizsgaltHattertar.family}")
        print(f"--> Háttértár modellje: {eppenVizsgaltHattertar.model}")
        print(f"--> Háttértár sorozatszáma: {eppenVizsgaltHattertar.serial}")
        if round((eppenVizsgaltHattertar.size) / math.pow(1024, 3)) <= 500:
            print(f"--> Háttértár mérete: {round((eppenVizsgaltHattertar.size) / math.pow(1024, 3))} GB")
        else:
            print(f"--> Háttértár mérete: {round((eppenVizsgaltHattertar.size) / math.pow(1024, 4))} TB")
        if eppenVizsgaltHattertar.rotation_rate is None:
            if "nvme" in eppenVizsgaltHattertar.interface:
                print(f"--> Háttértár típusa: NVMe csatlakozójú SSD\n")
            else:    
                print(f"--> Háttértár típusa: {eppenVizsgaltHattertar._interface} csatlakozojú SSD\n")
        elif eppenVizsgaltHattertar.rotation_rate > 0:
            print(f"--> Háttértár típusa: {eppenVizsgaltHattertar._interface} csatlakozójú HDD vagy SSHD\n")
        else:
            print(f"--> Segítség, nemtommivan.\n--> (Annyi mindenképp, hogy a programnak nem sikerült megállapítania a háttértár típusát.)\n")
except Exception as hibaLeirasHATTERTAR:
    print(f"--> Hiba! Leírás: {hibaLeirasHATTERTAR}\n")


Please post a [mre]. No one can tell what you might be doing wrong without seeing the code.

Thx for the answer. Okay, I'll include a GitHub link in a minute.

Questions should be self-contained, not depend on links to external sites.

Allright, I'll include the pySMART parts of my code.
